# Is it possible to translate x86 32 bit assembly code into equivalent JVM byte-code and execute it?

Tags: java, assembly, jvm, bytecode

Is it possible to translate x86 32 bit assembly code into equivalent JVM byte-code and execute it?

I have a Fortran library in .so form. I want to perform an assembly dump on it using GDB and then using a translator of some sort turn it into valid JVM bytecode.

Is this even possible?

For simplicity sake, let's assume I don't care about platform independence anymore. Both assembly and bytecode will run on the same machine.

Comment: Possible, but cheaper, faster, easier, and less buggy is to use JNI or even rewrite the library.

Answer (score 6):

Possible is nearly everything but I don't think you will find a tool that does this for you - therefore you would have to do it manually which could take you weeks or months depending on the size of the library.
Of course this may rise legal problems if the compiled library is a commercial one or copyright protected.

A better approach seems to me to develop a small [Java Native Interface (JNI)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/) wrapper in C/C++ and link the library to it. Then you will be able to call library functions from Java.

If you can get the Fortran source code you could try a JVM-Fortran compiler like [Fortran-to-Java](https://sourceforge.net/projects/f2j/). Then you would get native JVM byte code.

Comment: JNI is definitely a good solution to this problem. I was just wondering if a byte-code version of the library would bring any value in terms of performance and memory management.

Comment: +1: The byte code version would bring portability. e.g. it can be run on x64 without re-compilation and make full use of all registers and instructions set available. (As well as extra address space)

Comment: I updated my answer to include the legal aspect and JVM-Fortran compiler.